# get error when try to compile cuda programming

Tags: cuda

I have written a program to matrix multiplication in cuda programming.but I get several errors.I have mentioned r=errors what I have received.

`expected an identifier` code line `int a=0,b=0`

`expression must be a modifiable lvalue` code line `b=arr2[(a*b)+row]`

I have mentioned code below.I am very begging to cuda programming.please help me to solve this problem.

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    #define n 512
    #define r 512
    #define t 512
    #define b 512

    __global__ void metrimul(int *arr,int *arr2,int *arr3){

int row=threadIdx.x;
int column=threadIdx.y;

int result=0,i;
int a=0,b=0;

for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    a=arr[(column * n) + i];
    b=arr2[(i * n) + row];
    result=(a * b)+result ;
}

arr3[(column*n) + row]=result;


}

int main(){

int **h_arr1=(int **)malloc(sizeof(int *)* n);
int **h_arr2=(int **)malloc(sizeof(int *)* n);
int **h_arr3=(int **)malloc(sizeof(int *)* n);

int *d_arr1;
int *d_arr2;
int *d_arr3;

int i,j,k;

cudaMalloc((void **)&d_arr1,sizeof(int) * n);
cudaMalloc((void **)&d_arr2,sizeof(int) * n);
cudaMalloc((void **)&d_arr3,sizeof(int) * n); 

for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    h_arr1[i]=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    h_arr1[i]=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    h_arr1[i]=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
}

for(j=0;j<n;j++){
    for(k=0;k<n*n;k++){
        h_arr1[j][k]=1;
        h_arr2[j][k]=1;
    }
}

cudaMemcpy(d_arr1,h_arr1,n * n * sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_arr2,h_arr2,n * n * sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

metrimul<<<b,t>>>(d_arr1,d_arr2,d_arr3);

cudaMemcpy(h_arr3,d_arr3,n * n * sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

for(j=0;j<n;j++){
    for(k=0;k<n*n;k++){
    printf("%d",h_arr3[j][k]);
    }
}

return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a macro `b`:

```
#define b 512
```

Remember that macros are really just text replacements: All occurrences of `b` as a whole word will be replaced with `512`. Now the compiler sees this line

```
int a=0,b=0;
```

as:

```
int a=0,512=0;
```

And this is clearly a syntax error.

(Because this is a common cause of errors, it is a good habit to use all-upper-case names for macros. The stage where the macros are replaced is called preprocessing. Your compiler can show you what the source code looks like after preprocessing, for exanple with `gcc -E ...` or `cl /E ..`.)

Comment: @M Oehm i tried with your modification.now i don't get such errors.but when i compile this i get `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`...help me to solve this

Comment: A segmentation fault is access outside the valid memory. You should try to find the cause in a debugger. (But looking at your code, you try to copy ´n * n` ints from `h_arr` to `d_arr`, but your memory is not a contiguous vlock of ints. In your case, you must either allocate a single `n * n` block or do the copy the subarrays in a loop.)

Comment: And you allocate to the same array `h_arr1` three times. Surely that's a typo.

Comment: Even afer all of these trivial mistakes are fixed, this code cannot work correctly because of the structure of the host arrays of pointers used to hold the data.

Comment: extremely thank for your help...i think this is very difficult to understand the cuda programming...